# Providing program name with options to another program

Tags: c, arguments, argv, getopt

I have a program to which I pass one mandatory argument, which is a name of another program, and before it two possible options (lets assume one is called -v, the second one -a, their functionality is not important). What I need to do is to provide additional options for the second program. These are possible executions of the program in the terminal:

./program -a test

./program -v test

./program -v -a test

./program test

But I would like to also run this:

./program [any option from above] mandatory_argument [arguments launch options]

direct example:

./program -v -a second_program -g -foo

Is there a way to somehow distinguish two last options as options for second_program ? I have tried using optind, but unfortunately only the "second_program" is being recognised. Currently my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int vflag = 0;
    int aflag = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "va:")) != -1)
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'v':
                vflag = 1;
                break;

            case 'a':
                aflag = 1;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    if(argv[optind] == NULL) {
        printf("Missing mandatory argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        printf("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe call with: `./program -v -a "second_program -g -foo"`

Comment: Unfortunately I am obliged to not put second_program and its arguments in quotation marks

Comment: `If the first character of optstring is '+' or the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, then option processing stops
       as  soon as a nonoption argument is encountered` from `getopt` documentation.